# guard-haml is not compiling to html

Tags: ruby, haml, guard, ubuntu

I'm pretty much at my wits end here. Thus far, I've been able to get ruby 1.9.3 installed via rvm on kubuntu 12.04. I was also able to get sass, haml, and coffeescript running from the command line. Finally, I got guard up and running, but it seems that the guard-haml plugin is not communicating with haml. Thus far, I was able to get coffeescript, sass, and livereload running with little difficulty. So, I'm thinking the problem is either with the guardfile itself or guard cannot find the haml gem.

The Guardfile:

```
 # Sass
guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'

#CoffeeScript
guard 'coffeescript', :input => 'coffee', :output => 'js'

#LiveReload
guard 'livereload' do
    watch(%r{.+\.(css|html|js)$})
end

# Sample guardfile block for Guard::Haml
# You can use some options to change guard-haml configuration
# :output => 'public'                   set output directory for compiled files
# :input => 'src'                       set input directory with haml files
# :run_at_start => true                 compile files when guard starts
# :notifications => true                send notifictions to Growl/libnotify/Notifu
# :haml_options => { :ugly => true }    pass options to the Haml engine

guard 'haml' do
  watch(/^.+(\.html\.haml)/)
end
```

Please bear in mind that as far as Ruby is concerned, I'm a total novice, and this is not a rails project. I'm just using the preprocessors. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just facing the same issue. I solved this problem by using Gemfile and running guard through bundle command.
Here are the steps which may help you.

Guardfile:
Change:

```
guard 'haml' do
  watch(/^.+(\.html\.haml)/)
end
```

to

```
guard :haml, input: 'haml-src'
```

(this will search for .haml files inside haml-src folder and make .html files in root dir preserving the folder structure eg. haml-src/test/my.haml -> test/my.html)

Create Gemfile with:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-haml'
gem 'guard-coffeescript'
gem 'guard-sass'
```

After adding Gemfile to your project root dir just run `bundle install` command and then `bundle exec guard`